# dplyr::mutate when custom function return a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use `dplyr::mutate` to `group_by` data and create new columns, using custom function which return a vector, and the function takes a long time to bootstrap.

I know this can be implemented in base R, but is there a more elegent way in dplyr.

**Example (discarded):**

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(t1 = f(iris$Sepal.Length)[1], t2 = f(iris$Sepal.Length)[2])

f <- function(x) {
  return(c(2*x, x+1))
}
```

Is it possible to create two columns only call the function once in each group?

---

I made a mistake in the previous example.. Please check this example instead:

**Example:**

```
f <- function(x) {
  return(c(x*2, x+1))
}

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  
  group_modify(~ {
    .x %>% 
      mutate(t1 := f(mean(.x$Sepal.Length))[1], t2 := f(mean(.x$Sepal.Length))[2])
  })
```

---

**Method 1:**

Thank Darren Tsai for the answer! The problem is solved using `unnest_wider` in the new example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_modify(~ {
    .x %>% 
      mutate(t = list(f(mean(.x$Sepal.Length)))) %>% 
      unnest_wider(t, names_sep = "")
  })

# A tibble: 150 × 7
# Groups:   Species [3]
   Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    t1    t2
   <fct>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 setosa           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  10.0  6.01
 2 setosa           4.9         3            1.4         0.2  10.0  6.01
 3 setosa           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  10.0  6.01
 4 setosa           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  10.0  6.01
 5 setosa           5           3.6          1.4         0.2  10.0  6.01
 6 setosa           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  10.0  6.01
 7 setosa           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  10.0  6.01
 8 setosa           5           3.4          1.5         0.2  10.0  6.01
 9 setosa           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  10.0  6.01
10 setosa           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  10.0  6.01
# … with 140 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

**Method 2:**

Thanks Konrad Rudolph for his advise! A more flexible way to this question!

```
to_tibble <- function (x, colnames) {
  x %>%
    matrix(ncol = length(colnames), dimnames = list(NULL, colnames)) %>%
    as_tibble()
}
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(to_tibble(f(mean(Sepal.Length)), c("t1", "t2")))
```

Comment: In this example group_by is doing nothing, you are passing the same data to f.

Comment: As @zx8754 said, you need to remove `iris$`, otherwise `group_by` make no sense.

Comment: Sorry about that... I have updated a new example.

Comment: Your updated example does something *completely* different from your original code (once corrected), and Darren’s answer does something yet different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue with your code is that it passes a *vector* to `f`, so the result probably isn’t what you’re expecting:

```r
f(1 : 5)
# [1]  2  4  6  8 10  2  3  4  5  6
```

Your calling code will have to disentangle that.

You *can* do that, e.g. using the following helper:

```r
to_tibble <- function (x, colnames) {
    x %>%
        matrix(ncol = length(colnames), dimnames = list(NULL, colnames)) %>%
        as_tibble()
}
```

With that, you can now call your `f` inside `mutate` and provide target column names:

```
iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    mutate(to_tibble(f(Sepal.Length), c("t1", "t2"))
```

The advantage of this method is that it simplifies the calling code and harnesses `mutate`’s built-in support for producing multiple columns — no manual unnesting required.

---

Regarding your updated code/requirement, you can simplify that too using the helper function:

```r
iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    mutate(to_tibble(f(mean(Sepal.Length)), c("t1", "t2")))
```

Comment: Thank s a lot! This is really a more flexible approach. I need to learn more about dplyr programming.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment this `data.table` solution, but using `data.table` you could do the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(iris)

ff <- function(x) {
  return(list(2*x, x+1))
}

iris[, c("t1","t2") := ff(Sepal.Length), by = "Species"]
```

Would appreciate if someone with more reputation could make this a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could store mutated values in a list and unnest them to multiple columns with `unnest_wider` from `tidyr`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(t = list(f(mean(Sepal.Length)))) %>%
  unnest_wider(t, names_sep = "")

# A tibble: 150 × 7
# Groups:   Species [3]
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species       t1    t2
           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa      10.0  6.01
  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa      10.0  6.01
  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa      10.0  6.01
```

Comment: I am not sure. And the answer is already accepted. But if I use f e.g. f(5) it gives 10 and 6. Maybe the op wants to save the two outputs vor Sepal.Length e.g. 10.2 and 6.1? What do you think?

Comment: I don’t think this answer gives the correct result at all: it only preserves the first row’s value for every group, not all values. Compare the result of your code with that of mine and you’ll see that they are different (or just look at the output you’ve posted: all the `t1` and all the `t2` values are identical, even though all `Sepal.Length` values are different!).

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes I just add the `mean` part because the OP doesn't have it in the original post. Though I think it's not a big deal.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Sorry about that.. Your answer is very helpful! I made a lot mistakes the first time asked in starkoverflow.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Not sure what "big deal" means but your previous answer simply gave different, *incorrect* results that matched neither of OP's questions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the OP edit his question many times. In the earlier version he used `f(Sepal.Length)` instead of `f(mean(Sepal.Length))`. No matter the `mean` is used or not, the logic in my code is consistent, i.e. `mutate(t = list(f(...))) %>% unnest_wider`. It indeed matches all of the OP's requests.

Comment: @Darren Yes, that’s my point though: your initial answer was also wrong *for that question*. Look at my own answer, the code at the top is a reply to the OP’s initial question, it gives the correct answer, and the result differs from the code you wrote.